# Quantificar nova linha (\n) em regex

Tags: regex

Existe alguma forma de quantificar muitos parágrafos sem ser literalmente para usar com `PHP`?
`\d{54}`, por exemplo representa 54 dígitos, mas não dá pra usar `\n{54}`.

Quero numa só *regex* **pegar um dado que está a 54 novas linhas do restante.** 
Digitar `\n` 54 vezes é uma alternativa inviável, creio eu.

Comment: Dá um split por \n e pega a posição do array

Comment: Tem de ser usando regex pura? Nada de alternativas disponíveis nas linguagens?

Comment: Porque é que `\n{54}` não é uma opção?

Comment: @sergio, com o \n{54} não obtive resultados. Você já teve sucesso dessa forma?

Comment: @AntonioOliveira sim: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/hLm9f1xv/

Comment: Curioso, não é que agora funcionou. Obrigado!!: https://regex101.com/r/7kyfVA/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi. Você gostaria de pegar as 54 primeiras linhas de um texto?
Seria isso o que você está tentando fazer?

`(.*\n){54}`

Se não for, de mais detalhes mostrando o que você tem na tela, e o que quer pegar. Seria mais fácil pra entender visualizando o que você tem e o que você quer.

EDITADO

Não sei se você pode usar nomeando a captura, mas se puder acho que assim ficaria mais fácil:

`/(?P<paragrafo>.*)(.*\n){1,54}/g`

Ou então assim também deve funcionar:

`/(.*)(.*\n){1,54}/g`

A primeira captura `(.*)` vai pegar o primeiro parágrafo, a segunda captura `(.*\n){1,54}` vai pegar 54 parágrafos contando também o primeiro. Porém depois no seu código basta só ignorar essa segunda captura. E o modificador no final `/g` vai garantir que o regex faça capturas em quanto encontrar textos.

O esquema que coloquei `{1,54}` é que ele vai executar até o final, mesmo q a ultima bateria de captura não chegue a ter 54 parágrafos completos. Se colocar apenas assim: `{54}` Ele vai exigir que todas baterias de capturas tenha 54 parágrafos, e se o ultimo tiver por exemplo 53 parágrafos ou menos, ele vai ignorar e não vai executar a primeira captura da última bateria.

Espero que não tenha ficado tão confuso de entender ^^

Comment: texto a: "(.*?)  .... 54 parágrafos depois ... texto b: (.*?), (.*?), (.*?) ... entendeu?

Comment: Ahhh acho que entendi sim @AntonioOliveira, editei a minha resposta colocando outra solução no final. De uma olhada agora se dessa forma consegue resolver o seu caso. Desculpe a demora pra responder, fiquei o dia todo fora hoje.

Answer (score 1):

> Existe alguma forma de quantificar muitos parágrafos sem ser
>   literalmente para usar com PHP?

Sim, você pode usar o token `.*` em conjunto com `\n` para capturar um paragrafo inteiro.
Então coloque eles num grupo de captura e quantifique o grupo: `(.*\n){999}`

> Quero num só regex pegar um dado que está a 54 novas linhas do restante.

Você pode usar:

```
(.*\n){54}(.*)
```

**Explicação**

- `(.*\n){54}` Captura todos os dados irrelevantes das 54 linhas
- `(.*)` Após a captura das 54 linhas irrelevantes essa parte pega os dados até a quebra de linha seguinte, ou seja, captura tudo que esta no paragrafo 55.
- **Grupo de captura 1** - irá capturar todos os dados irrelevantes (só está em um grupo de captura para que a sequencia de *tokens* possa ser quantificada).
- **Grupo de captura 2** - irá capturar os dados que você quer, tudo que está na linha 55.

[Você pode ver o funcionamento dessa regex aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/CKB63Z/2)